# Is every point always "in a neighborhood" of every other point?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

The following axiom from the [neighborhood-definition of a topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Neighborhood_definition):

> "Every superset of a neighbourhood of a point $x$ in $X$ is again a neighbourhood of $x$."

leads me to believe that the whole set $X$ is always a neighborhood of every point (much like how $X$ is always an open-set). Therefore, a statement like "point $y$ is in a neighborhood of point $x$" is trivially true for all points because they all coexist in the neighborhood $X$ itself - even if the space is *disconnected*!

I often hear statements like "consider a point $y$ in the neighborhood of $x$." Am I correct to think that the use of the word "neighborhood" there is to colloquially mean "a small path-connected region around $x$" rather than the rigorous definition of a neighborhood? Because otherwise $y$ could be any point.

Moreover, is there a precise term for a subset $S$ of $X$ such that there exists a continuous path from $x$ to every other point in $S$?
$$
S \subseteq X\ \Big{|}\ \exists \gamma_y : [0,1] \xrightarrow[]{C} X\ |\ \gamma_y(0)=x,\ \gamma_y(1)=y\ \ \forall y \in S
$$

Comment: Yes, a space $X$ is a nbhd of every point of $X$. In the statement *consider a point $y$ in the nbhd of $x$*, however, the definite article (**the** nbhd) implies that we’re talking about a specific nbhd that was already mentioned. No, it does not in general mean *a small path-connected region around $x$*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : I see - thanks! Just wanted to check that a statement like "$+1$ and $-1$ share **a** neighborhood in $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$" is trivially true despite how strange it sounds to me. (I don't know how I got such a skewed perception of what a neighborhood is! I feel like "path-connected region around $x$" needs to be *something* haha).

Comment: The "path (-connected) component of $x$" is a maximal path-connected region containing $x$.

Comment: @MarkS. : Got it, thanks!